# Rails File_field Maximum stack size

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upload a photo by clicking a div following this tutorial: https://jsfiddle.net/rustybailey/2b7dD/

However when i click the div i get this error
         :Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I know it's a loop error. However I don't understand why.

Here's my code:

**Html**

```
    <div align="left" class = "upload" id = "upload">
    <%= f.file_field :image,:style => "display: none", hide_label: true,:id    => "imagem"%>
    <div style = "margin-left: 15px" id = "foto">
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
.upload{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color: #000000;
display: block;
}
```

**Js**

```
   $('#upload').on('click', function() {

   $('#imagem').click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

The #imagem div can't be inside #upload div

Comment: This issue should be caused by new version of gulp-minify-html and gulp-cache  [read this article may help you] (https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/issues/649)